# Quando e onde tratar exceções com Laravel no desenvolvimento de uma API

Tags: laravel, api, rest, exceção

Estou com algumas dúvidas quando se refere ao tratamento de erros em uma API.

- Devemos sempre tratar uma exception?
- Seria correto retornar uma mensagem como a que segue abaixo?

Retorno:

```
{
  "success" : false,
  "error" : {
    "message" : "<msg da exception>",
    "codeStatus" : "codStatus da exception"
  }
}
```

- Ou se devo capturar todas as exception e lançar uma 'message' personalizada?

Answer (score -2):

Quando eu crio uma API, eu sempre trato as exceções que minha aplicação lança porque o seu formato geralmente é lançado em HTML, e como é uma API, eu quero que seja lançado em formato JSON.

Eu crio minhas exceções personalizadas no formato:

```
{
   "messages": "algum erro"
}
```

Eu não costumo colocar success informando que deu errado ou certo porque o próprio HTTP Status Code já informa isso, mas em geral, o formato que você mencionou também é bom, vai do gosto.

As exceções padrões do Laravel normalmente são lançadas em formato HTML mesmo se no Header Accept estiver como [application/json]. Para resolver esse problema, eu fui em App\Exceptions\Handler.php e adicionei o seguinte código no método "render":

```
if($request->expectsJson())
        return $this->seuMetodoParaTratarExcecoes($request, $exception);
```

Dentro desse método, ai você coloca alguma verificação para transformar a exceção que seria lançada em HTML para uma em json.
Caso queira um exemplo:

```
 if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
        return response()->json([
            'messages' => 'Recurso não encontrado'
        ], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
```

Answer (score -3):

Tratar erros em uma API é uma parte crucial do desenvolvimento para garantir a robustez e a usabilidade do sistema. Quanto à sua pergunta sobre tratar exceções e retornar mensagens de erro, aqui estão algumas diretrizes a considerar:

Tratar exceções relevantes: Nem todas as exceções precisam ser tratadas de maneira específica. É uma prática recomendada lidar com exceções que podem ocorrer e afetar negativamente a funcionalidade da sua API. Exceções comuns a serem tratadas incluem erros de validação, erros de autenticação, erros de autorização e problemas de conexão com o banco de dados.

Mensagens de erro claras: Quando uma exceção é capturada, fornecer uma mensagem de erro clara e informativa é fundamental. Isso ajudará os desenvolvedores e usuários a entenderem o que deu errado. A mensagem de erro deve ser amigável e suficientemente detalhada para auxiliar na resolução do problema.

Retorno consistente: Utilizar um formato de resposta padronizado para os erros ajuda os consumidores da API a entenderem rapidamente o que aconteceu. O formato que você propôs, com uma indicação de sucesso/falha e uma estrutura para os detalhes do erro, é uma abordagem válida.

Código de status HTTP: Além da mensagem de erro, também é importante retornar um código de status HTTP apropriado. Códigos como 400 (Bad Request) para erros de entrada inválida, 401 (Unauthorized) para problemas de autenticação, e assim por diante, ajudam a comunicar o tipo de erro que ocorreu.

Segurança: Tenha cuidado ao expor detalhes técnicos ou sensíveis em mensagens de erro, pois isso pode ser explorado por atacantes. Forneça informações suficientes para a resolução do problema, mas evite revelar detalhes internos que possam comprometer a segurança.

Logs detalhados: Além de retornar mensagens de erro para o cliente, também é importante registrar essas informações em logs do servidor. Isso pode ajudar na depuração de problemas e na melhoria contínua da API.

Tratamento genérico vs. personalizado: Enquanto capturar e lançar exceções personalizadas pode ser útil para fornecer informações mais específicas sobre erros, não exagere. Tente encontrar um equilíbrio entre ter exceções personalizadas para situações especiais e usar exceções padrão para erros comuns.

Lembre-se de que cada aplicação e contexto podem ter requisitos diferentes em relação ao tratamento de erros. É importante considerar a experiência do usuário, a facilidade de depuração e a segurança ao decidir como tratar e comunicar exceções na sua API.