# Problemas com tratamentos de erros - PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

estou fazendo uma API e estou com um pequeno problema quando faço tratamentos de erros.. Para entender melhor vou colocar o codigo abaixo e depois explico o que acontece.

Minha rota para chamar minha API:

```
Route::get('lists', function () {
                    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

                    $user = new UserClass();

                    return $user->getList();
                });
```

Minha Classe:

```
    public function getList()
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->handleData();

            return response()->json([
                'message' => '',
                'data' => $result,
                'result' => true,
            ], 200);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => $e->getMessage(),
                'data' => '',
                'result' => false,
            ], 401);
        }
    }

    public function handleData()
    {
        $payload = request()->all();

        if (($payload['token'] ?? false)) {
            throw new \Exception("Necessário informar um token");
        }

        if (($payload['company_id'] ?? false)) {
            throw new \Exception("Necessário preencher todos os dados");
        }

        $data = [];
        $users = UserCompany::where('company_id', $payload['company_id'])->get();

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $data[] = [
                'name' => $user->first_name,
                'id' => $user->id,
            ];
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

O Retorno funciona em partes, a mensagem de exemplo que um token não foi informado ele mostra, porém está me retornando como um erro do sistema e não no formato JSON, veja abaixo como que está retornando:

```
<h1>
                                                    <i class="icon-power-off warning"></i> Error
                                                </h1>
                                                <p class=lead>We're sorry, but an unhandled error occurred. Please see the details below.</p>
                                                <div class=exception-name-block>
                                                    <div>Necessário informar um token</div>
                                                    <p>[...]/classes/User.php 
                                                        <span>line</span> 40
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
```

O que eu fiz ou deixei de fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que não está retornando da forma que você quer porque esse código está importando a `Exception` de forma errada:

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
```

Deveria ser assim:

```
} catch (\Exception $e) {
```

Antes, o `Exception` era importado do `App\UserClass\Exception`, e a segunda forma, importa da raiz `\Exception`.

---

A seguir, uma resposta alternativa.

Eu já respondi uma pergunta parecida, caso tenha curiosidade olhe este [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321948/quando-e-onde-tratar-exce%C3%A7%C3%B5es-com-laravel-no-desenvolvimento-de-uma-api).

O Laravel ele tem sua classe que trata exceções mas ele não diferencia se o que você está construindo é uma API ou um site normal.

Então você precisa implementar um tratamento para que exceções que ele lance retornem no formato Json.
Para isso, você precisa ir no arquivo `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` e editar a função `render` e implementar a seguinte lógica.

```
if($request->expectsJson())
{
    // Aqui você implementa um tratamento as exceções que necessitam de um retorno em JSON.
}
```

Assim como no post original, eu sugeriria que você fizesse dessa forma:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
... 

if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
    return response()->json([
        'messages' => 'Recurso não encontrado'
    ], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
```

Mas olhando para seu código, em vez de usar o código a seguir para lançar exceções:

```
throw new \Exception("Necessário informar um token");
```

Você usasse, e não haveria necessidade de um `try-catch`:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
... 

return response()->json([
    'message' => 'Necessário informar um token'
], Response::BAD_REQUEST);
```

E dessa forma, já elimina ter que mexer no `Handler.php` sem necessidade além de retornar num formato mais agradável com um código de exceção personalizado, mas é claro, exceções padrões você precisaria implementar um tratamento no `Handler.php`.

Comment: Entendi, porém da forma que você sugeriu por último eu ja estaria retornando dentro do metodo getList(), e da forma que ficaria não conseguiria captar o error dentro do Catch().. OU eu conseguiria?

Comment: Eu não havia percebido o `try-catch`... Mas não, você não trataria ele no `catch` mas retornaria a mensagem de erro mesmo assim. Analisando novamente seu código, acredito que ele não esteja captando a exceção por estar `Exception` e não `\Exception`. De qualquer forma, eu recomendaria não utilizar `try-catch` em casos como o seu, e sim, criar uma exceção personalizada ou retornar o erro como nos exemplos que dei.

Comment: @Crazy, perdoe meu equivoco em entender seu problema, editei a resposta e acredito que agora resolva seu problema. Mantive a resposta original também apenas para mostrar uma boa prática que costumo usar nos meus projetos.

Comment: era exatamente isso mesmo, faltou a Barra dentro Catch... Resolveu!!! Obrigado irmão!